# Solr localhost:8983 Not Found

Tags: java, solr, jetty

I have downloaded Solr 3.5.0. After unzipping I cd into solr\example and then run java -jar start.jar. The following message comes up:

> Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog jetty-6.1-SNAPSHOT
>   Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8983

If I then go to http://localhost:8983/ in my browser I get an error:

> Error 404 - Not Found. No context on this server matched or handled
>   this request. Contexts known to this server are:
>
> With nothing under the contexts.

If I go to http://localhost:8983/solr/admin I then get

> HTTP ERROR: 404
>
> Problem accessing /solr/admin. Reason:
>
> ```
> NOT_FOUND
> ```
>
> Powered by Jetty://

I am on a Windows7 machine if that helps. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The first error is normal, you should go to `http://localhost:8983/solr/` instead of `http://localhost:8983`. In fact the only web application running within jetty is contained in the `solr.war`, so you need to add the `solr` context to access it.

Then you should see the Solr welcome page where you can click on the `Solr Admin` link, which perhaps should point to the location you already tried: `http://localhost:8983/solr/admin`.

Anyway, when you try to access to http://localhost:8983/ Jetty should list the available contexts, but don't have any context on your list, while I have `/solr ---> org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext etc.`. This means the solr webapp is not starting correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Javanna.

I'm completely new to Solr and the book I'm following from doesn't give me anything about adding the context.

Are you able to help me out with completing that step?

Thanks

Comment: @user330936 Let's try...could you check the content of your `example/webapps` directory? Is there a solr.war? From your Jetty output it looks like it's starting without loading any app.

Comment: There is nothing in example/webapps

Comment: Really? Weird! Even in the solr zip file you downloaded?

Comment: Nope not a thing. There is in solr/webapp but nothing in solr/example/webapp

Comment: Ok, one step back. Does your zip file contain a solr directory as root? Mine contains `apache-solr-3.5.0/example/webapps`. Is yours different?

Comment: I have apache-solr-3.5.0/solr/example

Comment: I had downloaded apache-solr-3.5.0-src.tgz

I just downloaded apache-solr-3.5.0.zip and the example folder in this version contains a solr.war file

Then when I run java -jar start.jar I can the access http://localhost:8983/solr/ and http://localhost:8983/solr/admin

Thanks for all your help @javanna it is much appreciated

Comment: Oh. So simple. `go to http://localhost:8983/solr/ instead of http://localhost:8983` Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 4):

If you downloaded the source-version of Solr you need to run `ant example` to get the example code installed...

Would have been nice, if it were mentioned in the README ;o)

Comment: Note that you need to run this from the sub-directory 'solr', not from the root apache-solr folder.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem, you download apache-solr-3.5.0-src.tgz, but instead you want to use apache-solr-3.5.0.tgz or apache-solr-3.5.0.zip

apache-solr-3.5.0.tgz includes apache-solr-3.5.0/example/webapps/solr.war

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The Solr quick start guide says to run: `bin/solr start -e cloud -noprompt`

So I ran the command from Solr root directory. But I couldn't connect to Solr Admin UI on http://localhost:8983/solr/. I got this error: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8983: Connection refused`

I solved this using ianckc suggestion. First make sure you have a .war file in `example/webapps` and then run `java -jar start.jar` from `example` directory.

Answer (score 0):

HDP 2.2.4

1: Stop ambari server

2:
VERSION=`hdp-select status hadoop-client | sed 's/hadoop-client - \([0-9]\.[0-9]\).*/\1/'`
sudo git clone https://github.com/abajwa-hw/solr-stack.git /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/stacks/HDP/$VERSION/services/SOLR

3: comment Directory and File in lines
28 thru 42 and 61 thru 67
vi var/lib/ambari-server/resources/stacks/HDP/2.2/services/SOLR/package/scripts/master.py 
Comment out “Directory”

3: 
Before Install:
mkdir -p /var/log/solr

mkdir -p /var/run/solr

mkdir -p /opt/solr

chown -R solr:solr

4: Restart ambari

5: Follow Install Solr service — 
https://github.com/abajwa-hw/solr-stack

6: After Install ONLY:
su - solr

cd /opt/solr

ln -s /opt/solr/solr latest

mkdir -p /opt/solr/latest/server/solr/resources

7: Start Solr now FROM AMBARI (actually this IS NOT WORKING - the below manual start.jar is working)
or
cd /opt/solr/latest/example
[solr@sandbox example]$ java -jar start.jar

8: Solr INSTALL and RUN logs
/var/log/solr/solr-install.log